# Dini derivative of an unbounded function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

While reading some papers about derivatives of measurable functions I came across an interesting identity and, as the author wrote, it is easy to see that it holds. Well, for me it is not that easy and after many tries I am still not able to prove this fact in full generality:

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-\infty,+\infty]$ is any unbounded L-measurable function and $f_{p}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows: 
$$ f_{p}(x) := \begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if  $-p\leq f(x) \leq p$ } \\
-p, & \text{if $f(x) < -p$} \\
p, & \text{if $f(x) > p$}
\end{cases} $$

then $f_{p}$ is bounded, L-measurable and 
$$\mathrm{D}^{+}f(x)=\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{D}^{+}f_{p+}(x)$$
where $\mathrm{D}^{+}$ denotes upper right-hand Dini derivative.

The fact that $f_{p}$ is bounded and L-measurable is obvious, but the identity below is not as trivial as it may seem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Not so "easy" and the author claims.  Haven't got it yet.

Comment: How is $D^+f(x)$ defined if $f(x) = \pm\infty$? For $f(x) = +\infty$, do we say $D^+f(x) = 0$ if for every $\delta > 0$ there is an $y\in (x,x+\delta)$ with $f(y) = +\infty$ and $D^+f(x) = -\infty$ if there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(y) < +\infty$ for all $y\in (x,x+\delta)$? [And analogously for $f(x) = -\infty$?]

Comment: At points where $f(x)$ is not finite, perhaps define $D^+f(x)$ as that limit which makes the proof "easy".  I think the author just thought that, since it is obvious that $f$ and $f_p$ (for large $p$) have the same finite right derived numbers at any point where $f(x)$ is finite there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @Thomson I think that is not the case since even for points $x$ such that $f(x) < \infty$, the reasoning you have suggested, simply does not hold.

Comment: Take a look at this example: $f(x) := -\frac{1}{x}$ ($f(0) := 0$), then $D^{+}f(0) = -\infty$ and if you try to apply your reasoning to this function, you will not be able to find $p$ large enough to obtain equality.

Comment: @arystarch For that example, although $f_p$ and $f$ don't coincide on any neighbourhood of $0$, we still have $D^+f_p(0) = -\infty$ for all $p > 0$, since $f_p(x) = -p$ on $(0,1/p)$.

Comment: Same example but change $f(0):=-\infty$.  What's $D^+f_p(0)$ and what do we want for $D^+f(0)$ (if anything)?

Comment: Re: the comment above.  If a finite number r is a right derived number of $f$ at $x$ where $f(x)$ is finite there is a sequence $t_n\searrow 0$ so that $[f(x)+f(x+t_n)]/t_n \to r$.  But then $f_p$ for large $p$ also has this same right derived number $r$.  So the only messy part about thinking about the problem is to handle infinite derived numbers (not to mention the cases $f(x)=\pm\infty$).  If two functions $f$ and $g$  have the same set of right derived numbers then $D^+f(x)=D^+g(x)$ and $D_+f(x)=D_+g(x)$ (but don't forget infinite derived numbers).